# Dimension and basis of bounded linear maps (products)

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $X, Y, Z$ be finite dimensional normed spaces with bases $\{x_1,...,x_l\}$, $\{y_1,...,y_m\}$, $\{z_1,...,z_n\}$ respectively.

1. What is the dimension of $\mathcal{L} \{X \times Y; Z\}$ and give an example of a basis.
2. What is the dimension of $\mathcal{L^2} \{X, Y; Z\}$ and give an example of a basis.

I'm not entirely sure what the question means. But for 1. I said the dimension is l*m  (I used matrix multiplication). For the basis is it the column vectors? $(x_1y_1,....,x_ly_1)^T \ldots (x_1y_m,....,x_ly_m)^T$.

I am not sure about 2

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $L(X \times Y;Z)$ is the vector space of linear maps $T: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$.

For each you need to find a set of linear maps that form a basis of the respective spaces.

So for $L(X \times Y;Z)$ you need to find a collection of linear maps $T: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ that form a basis of the vector space $L(X \times Y;Z)$. The number of such linear maps is the dimension of the space $L(X \times Y;Z)$.

For question $1$ your collection of column vectors are not linear maps and thus do not form a basis.